# PHP OpenDir - Need to sort results

Tags: sorting, href, opendir

I want to display a directory that contains only PDF's.  I'd like the user to click on a given line and have the appropriate PDF displayed.  I copied some code from this site and had to modify it.  I put the "breaking return" tag so that each file would be displayed on a separate line.  The following code works fine, but I need the file listings to be sorted alphabetically.  I've tried the sort function for $thelist in several places, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I appreciate your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 if ($handle = opendir('hymn_lyrics')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
      {
            $thelist .= '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>'.'<br />';
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }       
?>
<P>List of Hymns:</p>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed it myself.    I used:

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code after reading another post here.  This works fine:

```
<?php
$files = glob('hymn_lyrics/*.pdf', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($files as $file)
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            $thelist .= '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'<br /></a>';
        }
    }
?>
<p>List of files:</p>
<p><?=$thelist?></p>
```